# Multiple Boundary Conditions for NDSolve in mesh with multiple interfaces

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, boundary-conditions

Here is my problem: I want to solve a Laplacian equation in a 2D geometry with multiple interfaces, each interface presenting a different boundary condition.

As for an example, I am working on a ring with BC1 on the outside and BC2 on the inside. I would like Mathematica to identify these two interfaces automatically (which I do manually for now, thanks to easy geometry).

Here is my code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
rego = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], Disk[{0, 0}, 4]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[rego];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: mesh]

```
sol = NDSolve[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 16], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 100]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
Plot3D[u[x, y] /. sol, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, u}]
```

which gives this nice plot:

[image: 3Dplot]

The trick is that I want to automize the selection of the boundaries in the Dirichlet conditions, because analytical expressions are easy to derive only in simple geometries.

I have had a look on other answers without being truly statisfied... must miss something.

Idea: use `ToBoundaryMesh[]` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question right, you could use boundary markers like so:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
rego = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], Disk[{0, 0}, 4]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[rego];
(*mesh["Wireframe"]*)
```

The `ToElementMesh` auto generated markers. You can inspect them:

```
groups = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
{1, 2}
```

Visualize the boundary elements that are grouped:

```
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp
```

[image]

Alternatively to colors, you can use `Dashing`:

```
dashes = Dashing /@ temp
{Dashing[0], Dashing[1/2]}
```

Show the boundary mesh:

```
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[#] & /@ colors)]]
```

[image]

Or with dashes:

```
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[#] & /@ dashes)]]
```

[image]

Now, generate boundary conditions that do not use a predicate but the boundary markers in the mesh.

```
bcs = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == RandomReal[], 
    ElementMarker == #] & /@ groups
{DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0.23219967730964175`, 
  ElementMarker == 1], 
 DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0.1493304332447205`, 
  ElementMarker == 2]}
```

Solve the equation as before.

```
sol = NDSolve[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, bcs}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
(*Plot3D[u[x,y]/.sol,{x,y}\[Element]mesh,PlotRange\[Rule]All,\
AxesLabel\[Rule]{x,y,u}]*)
```

Comment: This is great thanks, exactly what I needed!! Although I am colorblind so I will have to modify the `ColorData` line ;)

Comment: @Valacar, what would be a better scheme for color blind people? I'd like to change to that.

Comment: like numbers above the color segments (ranging from 1 to number of groups) for example. Also, I am thinking of B&W dots, hyphens, etc. ?

Comment: @Valacar, I hope this is better?

Comment: yes it is! Thanks

Comment: @Valacar Can you suggest a `ColorData[]` that you think would be less problematic for (partially) colorblind people? Is there something like that? I understand that red and green was a particularly bad choice but perhaps there is a ColorData that give acceptable results. Thanks.

Comment: I remember reading this nice article, could be a usefull basis: http://ristretto.black/are-your-documents-colourblind-friendly

Comment: @Valacar, thanks!